# Shannon's Entropy measure in Decision Trees

Tags: encoding, machine-learning, decision-tree, entropy, information-theory

Why is Shannon's Entropy measure used in Decision Tree branching?

> Entropy(S) = - p(+)log( p(+) ) - p(-)log( p(-) )

I know it is a measure of the no. of bits needed to encode information; the more uniform the distribution, the more the entropy. But I don't see why it is so frequently applied in creating decision trees (choosing a branch point).

Answer (score 5):

Because you want to ask the question that will give you the most information. The goal is to minimize the number of decisions/questions/branches in the tree, so you start with the question that will give you the most information and then use the following questions to fill in the details.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of decision trees, forget about the number of bits and just focus on the formula itself. Consider a binary (+/-) classification task where you have an equal number of + and - examples in your training data.  Initially, the entropy will be 1 since `p(+) = p(-) = 0.5`.  You want to split the data on an attribute that most decreases the entropy (i.e., makes the distribution of classes least random).  If you choose an attribute, A1, that is completely unrelated to the classes, then the entropy will still be 1 after splitting the data by the values of A1, so there is no reduction in entropy.  Now suppose another attribute, A2, perfectly separates the classes (e.g., the class is always `+` for `A2="yes"` and always `-` for `A2="no"`.  In this case, the entropy is zero, which is the ideal case.

In practical cases, attributes don't typically perfectly categorize the data (the entropy is greater than zero).  So you choose the attribute that "best" categorizes the data (provides the greatest reduction in entropy).  Once the data are separated in this manner, another attribute is selected for each of the branches from the first split in a similar manner to further reduce the entropy along that branch.  This process is continued to construct the tree.

Comment: According to your explanation can you explain why to need for log function?

Comment: If you note that `p(+) = 1 - p(-)`, having the `log` function in the equation gives it the nice property that the function has its minimum (zero) when `p(+)` is zero or one and has its maximum (1) when `p(+)` is 1/2 (i.e., when the two classes are equally likely). There is no need for the `log` function in the formula per se.  You could use an alternate symmetric function that is zero when `p(+)` is zero or one, has it's maximum at 0.5, and decreases monotonically with distance from `p(+) = 0.5`.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have an understanding of the math behind the method, but here is a simple example that might give you some intuition behind why this method is used: Imagine you are in a classroom that is occupied by 100 students. Each student is sitting at a desk, and the desks are organized such there are 10 rows and 10 columns. 1 out of the 100 students has a prize that you can have, but you must guess which student it is to get the prize. The catch is that everytime you guess, the prize is decremented in value. You could start by asking each student individually whether or not they have the prize. However, initially, you only have a 1/100 chance of guessing correctly, and it is likely that by the time you find the prize it will be worthless (think of every guess as a branch in your decision tree). Instead, you could ask broad questions that dramatically reduce the search space with each question. For example "Is the student somewhere in rows 1 though 5?" Whether the answer is "Yes" or "No" you have reduced the number of potential branches in your tree by half.